# iOS Game - Facebook SDK Like with custom button / programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

We're making a game in C++ (Cocos2d-x) for iOS and Android and we'd like to show a Facebook Like button in our game that works with the iOS Facebook SDK.

As it seems like the default way is to use the Facebook default UIKit button - but since we're making a game, we'd like to avoid having a UIButton above our OpenGLView.

Is there a way to do Facebook Like without the standard button?

Would it be legit to just create the Facebook button, but not show it and send a touch to the Facebook button programmatically? Is there a more elegant solution than that?

Comment: FBSDKLikeControl has only a few properties and the action of it cannot be customized. You have mentioned _Would it be legit_. Please let me know if you think you can customize action as legit is a later part to clear.

Comment: I actually meant the FBSDKLikeButton, one could create that and programmatically trigger a touch....probably not what Facebook intended. But how do they actually want Games to integrate like buttons?

Answer (score 0):

According to Facebook policy on Social Plugins point 4 of 13.

**"Don’t obscure or cover elements of social plugins."**

Source : [Link](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#socialplugins)

Comment: Well okay, but how can I then show a Facebook button in my game? How does Facebook want games on iOS and Android to show Like Buttons? Overlaying UI Elements inside game UI can't be the solution.

Comment: There is only one option, i.e to use [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios/like-button)

Comment: You mean to use a link and open an URL?

Comment: I mean to integrate like button functionality, the only legitimate procedure is to follow steps mentioned in [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios/like-button)